# Recover System TrayIcons

Tags: system

I run Ubuntu Mate 18.04.3 with Mate desktop. I've accidentally removed Network connection, Dropbox  and Power Usage icons from the System Tray. Could you please show me how to recover them? Thank you.

Comment: Can you right-click on the panel, click *Add to Panel*, then select the items you want? I have a couple of MATE systems, but not on Ubuntu; should be the same concept, though.

Comment: Thanks aj,I bit the bullet and reset the panel. Trying Add to Panel didn't show the applets I needed. Cheers